# How to get client port numbers for SQL connections in Go?

Tags: database, go

In postgres log each entry logs the client address accessing the DB as well as the port number, such as `10.1.1.1(4567)`, where `4567` is a port number for my application pod. I want to match that with my application logs but I couldn't find a way to log that port number `4567` in the Go application and I'm using the standard `sql` package and `sql.Open`.

Anyway to get that in Go? As the application must knows it for each connection, but it can be internal implementation of `sql` package so I cannot get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to log the source port of your connection to the database, here is my take on this with the postgres db I had available:

```
package main

import (
 "database/sql"
 "database/sql/driver"
 "net"
 "os"
 "time"

 pq "github.com/lib/pq"
 log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type customDriver struct {
}

func (d customDriver) Open(name string) (driver.Conn, error) {
 return pq.DialOpen(&customDriver{}, name)
}

func (d *customDriver) Dial(network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
 c, err := net.Dial(network, address)
 if err != nil {
  return nil, err
 }
 log.Debugf("Connecting from %s to %s", c.LocalAddr(), c.RemoteAddr())
 return c, nil
}

func (d *customDriver) DialTimeout(network, address string, timeout time.Duration) (net.Conn, error) {
 c, err := net.DialTimeout(network, address, timeout)
 if err != nil {
  return nil, err
 }
 log.Debugf("Connecting from %s to %s", c.LocalAddr(), c.RemoteAddr())
 return c, nil
}

func init() {
 sql.Register("custom_postgres", customDriver{})

 logLevel, logLevelExists := os.LookupEnv("LOG_LEVEL")
 if !logLevelExists {
  logLevel = "info"
 }

 logrusLogLevel, err := log.ParseLevel(logLevel)
 if err != nil {
  logrusLogLevel = log.InfoLevel
 }

 log.SetLevel(logrusLogLevel)
}

func main() {
 connStr := "postgres://testuser:testpass@34.69.4.107/testdb?sslmode=disable"
 db, err := sql.Open("custom_postgres", connStr)
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }
 defer db.Close()

 row := db.QueryRow("SELECT NOW()")

 var result string
 row.Scan(&result)

 log.Infof("DATABASE TIME: %s", result)
}
```

Then the output of this is as follows (one for regular execution and one with debug output, which includes source ip and port and destination ip and port)

```
~/Projects/go/q69587884 $ go run .                
INFO[0000] DATABASE TIME: 2021-10-16T02:39:36.710168Z   

~/Projects/go/q69587884 $ LOG_LEVEL=debug go run .
DEBU[0000] Connecting from 10.100.0.135:63616 to 34.169.24.137:5432 
INFO[0000] DATABASE TIME: 2021-10-16T02:39:39.291173Z   
~/Projects/go/q69587884 $
```

Comment: Thank you! That’s exactly what I want. Didn’t think of custom driver